# How to write moq unit test umbraco.web.models.rendermode(currentpage) in asp.net mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, moq

net mvc controller source code. I want to write moq unit test.

```
 public class abcController
 {
    [Authorization]
    public ActionResult findme()
    {
        var model = new Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel(CurrentPage);
        ViewData["abc"] = Umbraco;
        return View(model);
    }
 }
```

Now i want to write moq unit test for the above action method.

And added unittest project into my solution.
below my unit test project code

```
[TestFixture]
public class abcControllerTest
{   private IPublishedContent content;                                                 
[SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        content = Mock.Of<IPublishedContent>();                                    
     }                                                     
     [Test]
    public void findme_Test_Success()
    {   var contentMock = Mock.Get(content);            
        var abccontroller = new abcController();
        var result= abccontroller.findme() as ViewResult;
        Assert.IsNotNull(result); 
    }

}
```

this is not working for me.. getting object null ref exception

Note: `CurrentPage` is built in property for `IPublishedContent` interface of `RenderMvcController`

Note: Umbraco is a helper class UmbracoHelper of Umbraco dll

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of what you have tried so far so that help can be provided where needed.

Comment: Hi, I already posted one asp.net mvc action method "findme()". i want to write moq unit test for that action method. i added testproject. see below code i tried.

Comment: You needed to have that in the question. Like. Here is my controller. Here is the method I an trying to test. This is how I tried to test it when I ran into issues. Here are the issues I encountered. From there the community should be able to provide you with some assistance. Right now with what you have provided we can only guess. That does not allow the community to help much now, does it?

Comment: Again you need to edit the question with that information. It is of no help in the comments. Click the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43659467/edit) under the question

Comment: explaining about below line:                                                                                
 ViewData["abc"]=Umbraco;                                                                          Umbraco is a in build helper class UmbracoHelper of Umbraco dll

Comment: Take a look at this example and adjust it to suit your needs. There is just not enough context information in your question for me to be of much help to you. maybe this link will help. http://lecoati.com/es/leblog/unit-testing-a-umbraco-rendermvccontroller/

Comment: Thanks for sharing link. But tat link mainly for testing umbraco DLL file. I want write unit test for my code

Comment: If that is all you gathered from the link sent then you need to go back an read up on how to use that framework and also some tutorials on unit testing. Not much else I can do for you now.